# How to include css file for another page in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a main page and there is nav bar and in every section in nav there is another html file , like for example aboutus , the aboutus html file included in the php code with $location_of_file function.

```
<li class="menu-item">  <a href="<?php echo $location_of_file .'/aboutus.html'; ?>"> AboutUs</a> </li>
```

Now I want to add css file for the aboutus.html and I was trying to add it normaly like this because its html file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="aboutus.css" />
```

I trie also to add like the stylesheet css in the function.php and still not working

```
 wp_enqueue_style('aboutus',get_stylesheet_uri(),NUll,microtime());
    wp_enqueue_style('style',get_stylesheet_uri(),NUll,microtime());
```

do you have any idea how to add the css file for another page?

Comment: Why are you hard coding the menu when WordPress does this for you (and submenus too)? You can add a page specific class in WordPress too where the name of the page is the class, then you can style that.

Comment: The browser devtools console log and network tab are your friends. They'll give some details about why your css doesn't load properly. Worth your effort to figure out if you haven't already.

Comment: In the WordPress world (and most general purpose CMS world, too), don’t think about specific pages, but instead think about templates. For instance, instead of “about us page”, think of the “two column template” or whatever is more general. Further, break the individual parts of templates up, what my company calls “components”

Answer (score 0):

Enqueue style function will accept argument like below snippet:

> wp_enqueue_style( 'aboutus', $location_of_file . 'aboutus.css', NULL, microtime() );

Make sure second argument is the full URL of file.